# how to send a file using sockets in c

Tags: c, sockets

txt file from a client to a server. Right now, the file is sent to the server, but it's missing the content (empty file).

client.c

```
void send_file(char *filename, int sockfd)
{
    FILE *fp;
    int n;
    char data[BUFFERLEN] = {0};

    fp = fopen(filename, "r");

    while (fgets(data, BUFFERLEN, fp) != NULL)
    {
        send(sockfd, data, sizeof(data), 0)
        bzero(data, BUFFERLEN);
    }
}
```

server.c

```
void receive_file(char *filename, int sockfd)
{
    int n;
    FILE *fp;
    char buffer[BUFFERLEN];

    fp = fopen(filename, "w");
    while (1)
    {
        n = recv(sockfd, buffer, BUFFERLEN, 0);
        if (n <= 0)
        {
            break;
            return;
        }
        fprintf(fp, "%s", buffer);
        bzero(buffer, BUFFERLEN);
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: If you open files, you should also close them. You should always check the return codes of functions like `send`. How will you know that you were successful otherwise? You should read the documentation for functions like `send`, otherwise how will know how they operate (will it always send all requested bytes, for example, or can it send fewer)?

Comment: Actually, I made the checks in my code. I just removed it here to be more concise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while (fgets(data, BUFFERLEN, fp) != NULL)
{
    send(sockfd, data, sizeof(data), 0)
```

This is wrong. Not all lines have the size of `BUFFERLEN`. Don't send what you haven't read. Do not use `fgets` in this application. Use `fread`, and pass its return value back to `send`.

```
    n = recv(sockfd, buffer, BUFFERLEN, 0);

    fprintf(fp, "%s", buffer);
```

This is also wrong. `buffer` is not necessarily null-terminated. Do not use `fprintf` in this application, use `fwrite`, and pass the return value of `recv` back to it.

It also helps to open files in binary mode.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple fundamental bugs in both the client and the server.

```
while (fgets(data, BUFFERLEN, fp) != NULL)
```

A single line of text gets read into `data`, followed by:

```
    send(sockfd, data, sizeof(data), 0)
```

Two bugs on this one line:

1. this sends the ***entire*** `data` buffer. If the text line was 80 characters, that's what `fgets` read, but `BUFFERLEN` is 8192, this is going to ***attempt*** to send 8192 characters, instead of 80, since `sizeof(data)` is `BUFFERLEN`.
2. The return value from `send` gets completely ignored. This is always wrong, with sockets. The way that sockets work, if you request to `send()` either 80, 8192, or any number of bytes, you have ***no guarantees whatsoever*** that the requested number of bytes was actually sent on the socket. The sending socket may, very well, be able to send only ten bytes. Or may be just one byte. The return value from `send()` indicates how many bytes were actually sent. You must adjust your sending logic accordingly. So, for example, if you `fgets`ed and `send` 80 characters, and `send()` told you that only ten went out on the socket, you will then need to try again to send the remaining 70 characters. It is your responsibility to do so. And, of course, there's no guarantee that all 70 characters will be sent on the 2nd try.

And now, for problems with the server:

```
    n = recv(sockfd, buffer, BUFFERLEN, 0);
```

Here, you're checking the number of bytes received. This is correct, but then:

```
    fprintf(fp, "%s", buffer);
```

`%s` ***requires a '\0' terminated string***. If you guessed that you have no such guarantee from `recv()` you guessed correctly. You either need to make sure whatever you `fprintf` here is manually terminated by an extra `'\0'` character (and making sure that slapping on one in the `buffer` won't overrun it, corrupting memory), or use something else, like `fwrite`, perhaps.

All of the above bugs must be fixed in order for this to work correctly.